# Boost log rotating file - size exceeded

Tags: c++, logging, visual-c++, boost

I try to log with Boost library 1.61, rotating file once size exceeded 5Ko. But, *every time program runs, it begins from the first log file, exceeding max size* !

That is, it appends text to flog000.txt, then to flog001.txt.

But the desired behaviour was: append to the last file (flog002.txt) then continue with flog003.txt...

Here is my code:

```
#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_ostream_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>

void init()
{
   boost::log::add_file_log
      (
      boost::log::keywords::file_name = "flog%3N.txt",
      boost::log::keywords::open_mode = std::ios_base::app,
      boost::log::keywords::rotation_size = 5 * 1024,
      boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true
      );
}

int main()
{
   init();
   boost::log::sources::logger lg;
   boost::log::add_common_attributes();

   for (int i(0); i < 1000; ++i)
   {
      BOOST_LOG(lg) << "Hello : " << i << std::endl;
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Already saw these 3 questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020692/boost-log-clears-log-file , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505734/boost-logger-append-to-file and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037325/problems-with-file-rotation-after-adding-append-flag-in-boost-1-59-log-v2 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boost.Log - how to configure a text sink backend to append to rotated files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418917/boost-log-how-to-configure-a-text-sink-backend-to-append-to-rotated-files)

Comment: @AlanBirtles Not exactly, because here there is no file collecting. Also didn't see a working solution there...

Comment: looks the same to me, I agree that there isn't a satisfactory answer in that question but that doesn't mean it isn't a duplicate. boost log just doesn't seem to support this behaviour.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Mmm ... maybe, yes. But it would be very disappointing not to be able to do something so easy ...

Comment: This similar question is also unanswered (after the comment): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581405/how-to-configure-boost-log-for-writing-with-rotating-and-appending?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"There's no file collecting" - this is at least a part of the problem.

It does seem impossible to have scanning **and** append to an existing as well.

However, if you do scanning, you can at least prevent extra log messages from being *wrongly* appended to the older log files:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e955437eff22918b)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_ostream_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>

void init() {
    auto s = boost::log::add_file_log(
            boost::log::keywords::file_name = "flog%3N.txt",
            boost::log::keywords::open_mode = std::ios_base::app,
            boost::log::keywords::rotation_size = 5 * 1024,
            boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true
        );

    auto be = s->locked_backend();
    be->set_file_collector(boost::log::sinks::file::make_collector(
                boost::log::keywords::target = "./", // log file & target have same dir
                boost::log::keywords::max_size = 50 * 1024,
                boost::log::keywords::min_free_space = 100000
                ));

    be->scan_for_files(boost::log::sinks::file::scan_method::scan_matching, true);
}

int main() {
    init();
    boost::log::sources::logger lg;
    boost::log::add_common_attributes();

    for (int i(0); i < 1000; ++i) {
        BOOST_LOG(lg) << "Hello : " << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

After one run:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sehe sehe 5116 jun  6 00:27 flog000.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sehe sehe 5109 jun  6 00:27 flog001.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sehe sehe 2665 jun  6 00:27 flog002.txt
```

After two runs:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sehe sehe 5116 jun  6 00:27 flog003.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sehe sehe 5109 jun  6 00:27 flog004.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sehe sehe 2665 jun  6 00:27 flog005.txt
```

After three runs:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sehe sehe 5116 jun  6 00:28 flog006.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sehe sehe 5109 jun  6 00:28 flog007.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sehe sehe 2665 jun  6 00:28 flog008.txt
```